# Contact form 7 error on submit

Tags: ajax, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

first of all, i'm using

> contact form 7

and

> really simple captcha

My form is located at this URL: **mysite.com/#summary**

When i click on submit, the form redirects me here: **mysite.com/#wpcf7-f5514-p986-o1** instead of submitting the form properly.

Here's my network tab:

[image]

As you can see, **#wpcf7-f5514-p986-o1** is the value for **_wpcf7_unit_tag** sent with the ajax as well as the action url for the form (as you can see in the picture below):

[image]

After i get to **mysite.com/#wpcf7-f5514-p986-o1**, I also get two errors:

```
 Warning: unlink(C:/src/hg-www/wp-content/uploads/wpcf7_captcha/1819614282.png): Permission denied in C:\src\hg-www\wp-content\plugins\really-simple-captcha\really-simple-captcha.php on line 225
```

and

```
Warning: unlink(C:/src/hg-www/wp-content/uploads/wpcf7_captcha/1819614282.txt): Permission denied in C:\src\hg-www\wp-content\plugins\really-simple-captcha\really-simple-captcha.php on line 225
```

I don't really know what's wrong and how to solve it.

Any suggestions?

Some additional info:

- **wordpress** version is **4.4.2**
- **Contact form 7** version is **4.2.1**
- **Really simple catcha** version is **1.8.0.1**

The printed contact form code (if needed) is the following:

```
    <form name="" action="/create-your-system/#wpcf7-f5514-p986-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="5514">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.1">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f5514-p986-o1">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="ff2e2b253a">
</div>
<div class="wordpress-more-info-dropdown-div" id="dys-request-callback-dropdown">
<div id="contact-more-info-dropdown" class="wordpress-more-info-dropdown-div-label">
<span>Request a callback to discuss your quote</span>
<img class="wordpress-more-info-dropdown-div-arrow" alt="Heat Genius – Remote Heating Control" src="/img/default-images/wordpress-drop-down-more-infos-arrow.png">
</div>
</div>
<div class="inner-container">
<div class="HG-dys-contact-form-request-callback-container hideErrors" id="DYS-request-callback-container" style="display: block;">
<div class="left-column-contact-page"><div class="long-inputs"><p>Name (required)<br><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">
<input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
</span>
</p><p>Email address (required)<br><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email">
<input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
</span>
</p>
<p>Phone (required)<br><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-phone">
<input type="text" name="your-phone" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span>
</p>
<p>Post Code<br><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-postcode"><input type="text" name="your-postcode" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false"></span>
</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="right-column-contact-page">
<p>Notes<br><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><textarea name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span></p>
<p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-UID"><input type="hidden" name="your-UID" value="0b7f755668ad9ef6d1bf33b2e4302e3d72fb3dd9da089868566a7012dd0469b7" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" id="hg-system-uid" aria-invalid="false"></span></p>
</div>
<p>Insert captcha<br>
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_captcha_challenge_captcha-349" value="1819614282">
<img class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-captchac wpcf7-captcha-captcha-349 captcha" width="84" height="28" alt="captcha" src="http://192.168.1.250/wp-content/uploads/wpcf7_captcha/1819614282.png"><br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap captcha-349">
<input type="text" name="captcha-349" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-captchar captchaText" aria-invalid="false"></span></p>
<div class="clearfix">
</div>
<p class="contact-form-submit-button"><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit"></p>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, the problem seams to be the **#** as the url where the form is stored is **mysite.com/#summary** and apparently the hash in the url get replaced by the contact action url (which contains an hash as well).

I just tried the same settings in **mysite.com/** and it worked.

So now my question is: I can't get rid of the hash as it is part of an applcations, what can i do to avoid the replacing of the hash but still being able to send and use the form correctly?

**Contact form 7 settings:**

[image]

**Form content**

```
<div class="wordpress-more-info-dropdown-div" id="dys-request-callback-dropdown">
<div id="contact-more-info-dropdown" class="wordpress-more-info-dropdown-div-label">
<span>Request a callback to discuss your quote</span><img class="wordpress-more-info-dropdown-div-arrow" alt="Heat Genius – Remote Heating Control" src="/img/default-images/wordpress-drop-down-more-infos-arrow.png"></div>
</div>
<div class="inner-container">
<div class="HG-dys-contact-form-request-callback-container" id="DYS-request-callback-container" >
<div class="left-column-contact-page">
<div class="long-inputs">
    <p>Name (required)<br>[text* your-name]</p>
    <p>Email address (required)<br>[email* your-email]</p>
    <p>Phone (required)<br>[text* your-phone]</p>
    <p>Post Code<br>[text your-postcode]</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="right-column-contact-page">
    <p>Notes<br>[textarea your-message]</p>
    <p>[text your-UID id:hg-system-uid]</p>
</div>
<p>Insert captcha<br />
[captchac captcha-349 class:captcha size:l]
[captchar captcha-349 class:captchaText]
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<p class="contact-form-submit-button">[submit "Send"]</p>
```

and **additional settings:**

```
on_sent_ok: "location = '/form/#requestCallback;'"
```

Comment: Can you attach your contact form 7 settings page?

Comment: I've just edited the question

Comment: ... i got a downvote because?

Comment: It wasn't me :) Anyway I would like to see wpcf7-f5514-p986-o1  setting and global wpcf7 settings

Comment: yeah i know it wasn't you, i just don't get the downvotes sometimes...anyway, how can i show those settings to you? you mean the actual plugin code or..?

Comment: Just print screen of your settings on admin page

Comment: Just edited with the pics

Comment: Just copy paste here contents of "Form" and "Additional Settings" tabs

Comment: `location = '/form/#requestCallback;'"` there's the `#` comes from...

Comment: @Nick did you managed to fix the **unlink** error? I'm having the same issue but on Wamp Server (localhost).